# Finding similar users based on String preperties

Tags: machine-learning, data-mining

Im a software engineering student, and new to Data Mining, I want to implement a solution to find similar users based on their interests and skills (Strings sets).

I think I cannot use K nearest Neighbors using an edit distance(Levenshtein or ..)

If someone could help with that please

Comment: There is not much you can do without extracting the features from these strings. In sklearn (beautiful python-based ML-lib) [this](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/feature_extraction.html) part of the documentation applies to this kind of preprocessing. The whole preprocessing is somehow model-driven. Your features may be bool, ordinal or nominal and your preprocessing should reflect this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The first thing you should do is convert your data into some *reasonable representation*, so that you will have a well-defined notion of distance between suitably represented users.

I would recommend converting all strings into some canonical form, then sorting all `n` distinct skills and interest strings into a dictionary `D`. Now for each user `u`, construct a vector `v(u)` with `n` components, which has `i`-th component set to 1 if the property in dictionary entry `i` is present, and 0 otherwise. Essentially we represented each user with a characteristic vector of her interests/skills.

Now you can compare users with [Jaccard index](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jaccard_index) (it's just an example, you'll have to figure out what works best for you). With the notion of a distance in hand, you can start trying out various approaches. Here are some that spring to mind:

- apply hierarchical clustering if the number of users is sufficiently small;
- apply [association rule learning](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Association_rule_learning) (I'll leave you to think out the details);
- etc.